# Basic JavaScript button interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm new to JavaScript and Node.js.

I'm trying to get a button in my webpage to call a method in my controller when clicked, but so far I'm getting no response from my controller.

How do I call the `.submitEntry()` function from my button?

Here's the *index.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html ng-app='app'>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller='GameController' class='container'>
        <h1>Palindrome Game</h1>
        <h2>Submit a new word!</h2>
        <form role='form'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <input ng-model="name" class='form-control' placeholder="Your name">
                <input ng-model="word" class='form-control' placeholder="Word">
                <button ng-click='submitEntry()' class='btn btn-default'>Submit word</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <h2>Top Scores</h2>
        <ul class='list-group'>
            <li ng-repeat="score in scores | orderBy:'-points'" class='list-group-item'>
                <strong>{{score.name}}</strong> {{score.points}} points
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='ng/app.js'></script>
</body>
```

And here's the *app.js* file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

const button = document.getElementById('myButton');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) 
{
  console.log('button was clicked');
});

app.controller('GameController', function($scope, GameService) 
{
    console.log("Debug 0");

    $scope.submitEntry = function() 
    {
        if (typeof $scope.name === 'undefined' || typeof $scope.word === 'undefined') 
        {
            return;
        }
        var entry = {
            name: $scope.name,
            word: $scope.word
        };
        GameService.submitEntry(entry).success(function(points) 
        {
            $scope.word = undefined;
            GameService.getScores().success(function(scores) 
            {
                $scope.scores = scores;
            });
        });
    };

    GameService.getScores().success(function(scores) 
    {
        $scope.scores = scores;
    });
});

app.service('GameService', function($http) 
{
    this.getScores = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/getScores');
    };
    this.submitEntry = function(entry) {
        return $http.post('/api/submitEntry', entry);
    };
});
```

Thank you very much! Any help that could point me in the right direction will be very appreciated.

Comment: i think u forget to put id in your button div. <button ng-click='submitEntry()' class='btn btn-default id="myButton"'>Submit word</button>

Comment: can you please share the error you are getting in your console?

Comment: I'm getting no error in the console.

Comment: is your api returning success?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using an old version of angularJS?

Comment: Is debug 0 ever logged? besides, avoid using `'` with angular tags (like ng-click). Use `"` instead. Also, the first part where you're binding to button will **never** work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple button that displays an alert once clicked.

```js
function Channels($scope) {
 $scope.test = function() {
   alert('button clicked!')
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Channels', Channels);

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body ng-controller="Channels">
   <button ng-click="test()">
    test
   </button>
 </body>
```